# VScode Python - Send selected lines to terminal adding extra lines

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

As mentioned, a new line is being added everytime i try to send multiple lines to the terminal

Input (selection)

```
import time
import os
print('test')
```

Output (on pressing shift+enter)

```
>>> import time
>>>
>>> import os
>>>
>>> print('test')
test
>>>
```

Any idea on how to fix this? im not able to send functions at all since it breaks the indent.

Comment: how are you sending these lines to the terminal, and why?

Comment: usually its shift+enter. Mostly use it for loading the program line by line and verifying it - makes it simpler to modify and test

Answer (score 1):

If you're on Windows then it means you are running an outdated copy of the extension (you should be on 2018.9.1 as that fixes this issue). Your example with a function should be working:

```
import time
import os
print('test')
def main():
    pass
```

And the result:

```
>>> import time
>>> import os
>>> print('test')
test
>>>
>>> def main():
...     pass
...
```

Comment: Im on version 2018.9.1 - It was working fine all along, one fine day it doesnt work

Comment: Then please open an issue at https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python .